# How to make lock screen widget wallpaper android

Tags: android, widget, lockscreenwidget

Actually I am working on music player widgets, I made home widget for music player and it is working fine,but when I play any song I need to show that song image on android lock scren, I tried lockscreen widget but I didn't get it please help me

Home widget:

```
<receiver android:name=".widgets.HomeWidgetProvider">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
  </intent-filter>  
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
    android:resource="@xml/app_widget_provider"/>
</receiver>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:initialLayout="@layout/home_widget_layout"
                    android:minHeight="10dp"
                    android:minWidth="250dp"
                    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000000"
                    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly whats happening when you try doing that? Also it will be helpful if you'll post your code (not just manifest)

Comment: simple i want to show songimage on lock screen

Comment: lock screen wallpaper programatically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable your widgets in lockscreen too you have to set widgetcategory to keygaurd in your manifest as:

```
<android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen">
```

You can find detailed documentation in: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen

Answer (score 0):

Actually Google did away with lock screen widgets in Android 5.0 (Lollipop). If you simply want to display the album art on the lock screen, then let your app implement [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) (or [MediaSession](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html) for API 21 and up)

If you want more functionality, the you can create you own interactive lock screen experience for your users with the [Adenda](http://adendamedia.com) SDK (I'm affiliated with Adenda for full disclosure)